# R Shiny, Creating reactive plot based on user uploaded file

Tags: r, shiny, heatmap, bioinformatics, reactive

I am developing an app to (among other things)
1. Allow a user to upload a csv dataset (this appears to work)
2. Plot a heatmap based on the user selected file in a separate tab

The app appears to run however i cannot get the heatmap to plot the data selected by the user, I assume it needs to be reactive in some way but I am unable to call the uploaded file.

My code thus far

UI:
    library(shiny)

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("File Input",
    sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file","Upload the File"),
      tags$hr(),
      h5(helpText("Select the read.table parameters below")),
      checkboxInput(inputId = 'header', label = 'Header', value = FALSE),
      checkboxInput(inputId = "stringAsFactors", "stringAsFactors", FALSE),
      br(),
      radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Separator', choices = c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t', Space=''), selected = ',')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("tb")

    )
    )),
  tabPanel("Heatmap",
    plotOutput('heatmap', width = "100%", height = "500px")

))
))
```

Server

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input,output,session){

  data <- reactive({
    file1 <- input$file
    if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
    read.table(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep, header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = input$stringAsFactors)

  })


  output$filedf <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    input$file
  })


  output$sum <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    summary(data())

  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    data()
  })


  output$tb <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(data()))
      h5("Powered by copious amounts of coffee", tags$img(src='coffee.png', heigth=200, width=200))
    else
      tabsetPanel(tabPanel("About file", tableOutput("filedf")),tabPanel("Data", tableOutput("table")),tabPanel("Summary", tableOutput("sum")))
  })
 mps<-reactive({
if(is.null(file_to_read)){
  return()


   }
plots<-reactive({
   output$heatmap <- renderPlot({ heatmap(data, main = "heatmap")
       })})
    })})
```

Is there a way to name the data as an object to use in the heatmap e.g.

```
mat<-as.matrix(user uploaded file, row.numbers=1)
output$heatmap <- renderPlot({ heatmap(mat, main = "heatmap")
```

Comment: What if you use `mat <- as.matrix(data(), row.numbers=1)` ?

Comment: I've tried a few variations of this but the heat map tab just remains blank.

Comment: Thanks its now attempting to produce the heatmap, but with the error warning "'x' must be a numeric matrix".   This error appears before and after choosing the upload file, which is why I believed I had to make the function and its components reactive to reproduce the plot once the dataset has been chosen.

Comment: @Niall Can you edit your question to what you currently have in your code for review? I was able to reproduce without any errors at my end. And what data file are you trying? Could it be creating a `character` matrix and not `numeric`? You might want to convert to matrix without rownames and then add rownames afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

@Niall - here is what I have to create a heatmap. Hope this is helpful. I tested it with `mtcars` in a .csv file:

```
"mpg","cyl","disp","hp","drat","wt","qsec","vs","am","gear","carb"
"Mazda RX4",21,6,160,110,3.9,2.62,16.46,0,1,4,4
"Mazda RX4 Wag",21,6,160,110,3.9,2.875,17.02,0,1,4,4
"Datsun 710",22.8,4,108,93,3.85,2.32,18.61,1,1,4,1
...
```

With `header` option selected in your shiny app.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("File Input",
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 fileInput("file","Upload the File"),
                 tags$hr(),
                 h5(helpText("Select the read.table parameters below")),
                 checkboxInput(inputId = 'header', label = 'Header', value = FALSE),
                 checkboxInput(inputId = "stringAsFactors", "stringAsFactors", FALSE),
                 br(),
                 radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Separator', choices = c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t', Space=''), selected = ',')
               ),
               mainPanel(
                 uiOutput("tb")

               )
             )),
    tabPanel("Heatmap",
             plotOutput('heatmap', width = "100%", height = "500px")
    ))
)

server <- function(input,output,session){

  data <- reactive({
    file1 <- input$file
    if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
    read.table(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep, header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = input$stringAsFactors)
  })

  output$filedf <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    input$file
  })

  output$sum <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    summary(data())

  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    data()
  })

  output$tb <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(data()))
      h5("Powered by copious amounts of coffee", tags$img(src='coffee.png', heigth=200, width=200))
    else
      tabsetPanel(tabPanel("About file", tableOutput("filedf")),tabPanel("Data", tableOutput("table")),tabPanel("Summary", tableOutput("sum")))
  })

  output$heatmap <- renderPlot({ 
    if (is.null(data())) {
      return()
    } 
    heatmap(as.matrix(data()), main = "heatmap")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @ben, Its running now using your adjustments to the code. I think the "'x' must be a numeric matrix" warning was due to the nature of mydataset.

Comment: Glad to hear - that makes sense.